# X equivalent of Windows's 'transparency key'

Tags: linux, xorg, remote-desktop

on Windows I had a program that would run and make a couple API calls to change the window properties on `mstsc` (Microsoft Terminal Services Client) to set the transparency key. I could then set the wallpaper on the computer I was remoting in to to that color and it would be completely transparent, even allowing mouse clicks through it. This allowed for a simplistic Remote Desktop seamless mode.

Is there an equivalent to that I can use on Linux? I can recompile my own version of rdesktop if need be, I'm just not finding any way to set a specific color transparent.